# How to save the delivery status of SMS in Default SMS Table in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am developing Android application for sending SMS. After sending the SMS I update Default sms table.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", address);
values.put("body", msg);
values.put("type", 2);
values.put("date", date);
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

But I do not know how to keep it, when it comes to the delivery report. I would be very grateful for any ideas.

After receiving a delivery report to update SMS Default Table and retain the status of delivery. For example, when the SMS has been sent, the column "type = 2". How to record for delivering SMS? Sorry for bad English. Thank you

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a column in SMS table named **delivery_status**. In addition previous fields, you should fill it when it comes to the delivery report. I have saw it filled with *2 value*. notice some of phone doesn't have it and instead of that there is **delivery_date** column that you should put it current time.

```
public static int updateSmsStatus(Uri smsUri, int status, int delivery_status) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("status", status);
    values.put("delivery_status", delivery_status);
    return G.getContext().getContentResolver().update(smsUri, values, null, null);
}
```

Comment: there is many phones dosn't contain delivery_status or delivery_date is there an alternative column ?